# @ngrx/store asking to install @angular/core@^10.0.0 however we have "@angular/core": "^11.0.5"

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, angular11

**When trying to latest ngrx/store in angular 11, it is giving warning to install angular 10.**

@ngrx/store@10.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Following is package json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
"@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
"@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^3.8.1",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.3",
"sass-loader": "~6.0.7",
"tslib": "^2.0.3",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
"zone.js": "^0.10.3"
```

}

**npm install gives following WARN**

```
npm WARN @ngrx/store@10.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

How to handle this situation?

Comment: @ngrx/store module have peerDependenicies @angular/core@^10.0.0 that's why you getting warning. However it will work with A11 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's totally, fine.

Currently (01.01.2021), there is no ngrx version for A11 (no version 11), but version 10 works perfectly with A11 and you can use it, despite the warning.

If this is the only warning you get, then feel free to add `--force` flag to proceed with the upgrade.